# Transform dataframe to have a row for every observation at every time point

Tags: python, pandas, transform

I have the following short dataframe:

```
A   B   C
1   1   3
2   1   3
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   0   0
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
A   B   C
1   1   3
2   1   3
3   0   0
4   0   0
5   0   0
1   1   3
2   1   3
3   2   3
4   2   3
5   0   0
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to accomplish, if you post your attempt it will give us a better idea or perhaps some pseudocode.

Comment: Your desired result doesn't seem to conform to ```an entry for every observation of A, at every time point B```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` with `unique` `A`s and `B`s.  Then `reindex`.

```
cols = list('AB')
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.A.unique(), df.B.unique()], names=cols)
df.set_index(cols).reindex(mux, fill_value=0).reset_index()

    A  B  C
0   1  1  3
1   1  2  0
2   1  0  0
3   2  1  3
4   2  2  0
5   2  0  0
6   3  1  0
7   3  2  3
8   3  0  0
9   4  1  0
10  4  2  3
11  4  0  0
12  5  1  0
13  5  2  0
14  5  0  0
```